# How to assign a name to a control_flow in prefect?

Tags: python, python-3.x, prefect

How do you assign a `name` to a `merge` task in a flow?

```
thing_three = merge(thing_one, thing_two)
```

The ultimate goal is to retrieve `merge` using `flow.get_tasks(name="thing_merger")`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most straightforward way to handle this would be to use:

```
thing_three = merge(thing_one, thing_two)

thing_three.name = "thing_merger"
```

Then when you call `flow.get_tasks(name="thing_merger")`, it'll return:

```
[<Task: thing_merger>]
```